# Ensure at least one checkbox is selected in angular

Tags: angularjs

I need to validate that at least one checkbox, in 3, has been selected. I can't use radio buttons because two of the options are can be selected and exclude the third. I'm not really sure if it's best to put these checkboxes into a model array, rather than binding them to separate models and creating a longer `ng-required` expression. The docs aren't particularly helpful in describing what 'best practise' is for this sort of thing...

Code:

```
<div class="form-inline form-group">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <h4 class="card-title left test-list-header">Balcony</h4>
    </div>
</div>

<fieldset class="form-group">
    <input type="checkbox" id="balconyBalcony" ng-model="balcony">
    <label for="balconyBalcony">Balcony</label>
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="form-group">
    <input type="checkbox" id="patioBalcony" ng-model="patio">
    <label for="patioBalcony">Patio</label>
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="form-group">
    <input type="checkbox" id="noBalcony" ng-model="noBalcony" ng-disabled="balcony || patio">
    <label for="noBalcony">No</label>
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="form-group" ng-show="noBalcony && !patio && !balcony">
    <div class="md-form">
        <input
            type="text"
            id="{{ Plot::FIELD_BALCONY_NOTES  }}"
            class="form-control"
            name="{{ Plot::FIELD_BALCONY_NOTES }}"
            inline-edit
            inline-edit-callback="UpdateHandler()"
            ng-model="Model.BalconyNotes.Value"
            ng-class="{ invalid: createPlot.balconyNotes.$invalid && submitted, valid: createPlot.floor.$valid }"
            ng-init="Model.BalconyNotes.Value = '{{ old(Plot::FIELD_BALCONY_NOTES) or $Model->BalconyNotes }}'" ng-required="noBalcony">
        <label for="{{ Plot::FIELD_BALCONY_NOTES }}" data-error="@{{ Model.BalconyNotes.ValidationMessage }}" class="w-100">Comments</label>
        <span class="help-block" ng-show="createPlot.balconyNotes.$invalid && submitted">As there is no balcony or patio, you must enter a comment</span>

    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Would checking `if(!($scope.balcony || $scope.patio || $scope.noBalcon)){ // you gotta select atleast one error }` on submit click or your required event work? Or display message in your html for the same condition

Comment: @Developer That could be done in the template itself.

Comment: You don't have a form attribute, and none of your checkboxes have names. You need to read the documentation of forms again.

Comment: @cst1992 - correct..just updated the comment and saw your answer :) It depends on the business whether to show that note in screen always or to alert on submit of some event..

Comment: This a section of a form, not the entire form. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `ng-required` built in `directive` to validate your form.

Like this:

```
<form novalidate name="myForm" ng-submit="mySubmitFunc()">
      <label>Checkbox 1
        <input ng-required="!(cb2 || cb3)" ng-model="cb1" type="checkbox">
      </label>
      <label>Checkbox 2
        <input ng-required="!(cb1 || cb3)" ng-model="cb2" type="checkbox">
      </label>
      <label>Checkbox 3
        <input ng-required="!(cb1 || cb2)" ng-model="cb3" type="checkbox">
      </label>
      <input type="submit" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid" value="submit">
    </form>
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jcaLjuzk/) demonstrating how to handle such logic.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a validation line:

```
<div ng-show="myForm.$submitted">
    <p  style="color: red" ng-show="!myForm.balcony && !myForm.patio && !myForm.noBalcony">You must select at least one of the options above.</p>
</div>
```

That div shows when the user tries to submit and the p shows when none are selected.

Your button will also need an ng-disabled directive with the same condition.